# Using methods on anonymous classes

Tags: java, class, anonymous

I'm trying to figure out if what I want to do is even possible. I've looked around and google hasn't been super helpful, at least in this specific case.

Here's what I'm trying to do. The assignment I'm working on is designed to be run multiple times from the command line, with two possible sets of arguments: ["CREATE" "cardType"] or ["VERIFICATION" "accountNumber" "transactionAmout"] . Every time a "CREATE" flag is passed, an anonymous instance of the class is created - the constructor creates the various data fields associated with the class, and writes them to a file, and the program exits. Okay so far.
Here's a snippet from the constructor (there's several of these, but they're all pretty much identical):

```
if(issuer.compareTo("AE") == 0)
    {
        try
        {
        cardType = "American Express";
        firstDigit = 3;
        accountNumber = accountNumberGen(firstDigit);            
        memberSince = new java.util.Date();
        limit = setLimit(accountNumber);
        output.write(accountNumber + "|" + cardType + "|" +
                memberSince + "|" + limit + "\r\n");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.printf("An unexpected error occured. Sorry.\n"
                    + "American Express Constructor.");
            System.exit(0);

        }
```

So, here's the what I'm trying to figure out. The next step is the "VERIFICATION" flag. If the verification flag is passed from the command line, I need to go into the file, read out the data stored in it, make any changes, and write it back to the file. Again, okay so far. Here's the problem:

Since there's no instance of the class, I can't invoke methods in the class. However, the Verification method doesn't need an instance of the class to do its job - it's dealing entirely with command line arguments, and reading/writing to the file. So, how can I go about anonymously invoking methods within a class? Do I have to create another Verification class, or just move the method into my main class? I'm a little hesitant about either of those, because the assignment implies that there should be one class which handles creation and verification. Or, another possibility, is my logic in approaching this problem just flawed?

This code is a work in progress - exceptions will become more specific and any open filestreams are going to be closed, etc.

Comment: What constructor is that a snippet from if there's no Class? I think we need some details regarding the actual object structure here. Also, how much control do you have over any of these? It sounds like you should be using an interface with many implementing classes (or an abstract super-class).

Comment: Here's what I mean by anonymous, I might have used to wrong terminology...

`public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
               
        inputValidation(args);
        
        if (args.length == 2)
             new Account(args[1]);
       
         
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question/assignment properly (and I'm not sure that I do, what exactly are the requirements of the assignment? Are you required to use anonymous classes? There's really no such thing as an anonymous method in Java, only anonymous classes.), it sounds like you might want a one-off Vertification class, or a static method.

**The one-off method:**

```
Verification v = new Verification(commandLineArgs);
v.verify();
// Done with 'v'
```

**The static method... method:**

```
Verification.verify(commandLineArgs);
```

Where the method is defined in the class as:

```
public class Verification {
   ...
   public static void verify(String ... commandLineArgs) {

   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: This sound promising. I think this might be the way to go.

Comment: Update....got this working, thanks so much. I've got another question, though, because of the fact that I'm still using anonymous calls:
new Account(args[1]);
new Verification(args[1],args[2]);
Would it be better name them, even if there's no use for them after they're declared? The classes themselves are doing everything that needs to be done (writing, reading, processing, etc). Or, are my classes just poorly designed?

Comment: If all you're doing is calling the constructors, then your classes are poorly designed. You should pull the constructor code into a static method. (The second method I suggested.) Constructors should only be used for instance variable initialization, and any other kind of setup that is **required** for that object to be used, but any additional execution is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will keep it in mind for the future. The final program, in a very sloppy way, is doing what you suggested - the constructor calls various static methods. I'm relatively new to OOP, and I think I'm still stuck in a procedural mindset.

Comment: If you want to send me your assignment (my email is listed in profile) then I'll type up an OOP-friendly version for you to look at. When is your assignment due?

Comment: The assignment is due Tuesday. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of time between now and then for re-building my code, and right now, it works. However, if you would be willing to take a look at the code for me and give me your feedback, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Also, I might be an idiot, but I can't find your email. Are you referring to the one listed on your website?

Comment: Sure, any email you can find. I was actually planning on sending you the code the day after the assignment. For obvious reasons. :)

Answer (score 3):

One acronym: [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

Yes, you could do all kinds of magic, calling methods via reflection, etc. But why bother?

Create a main method which takes the first argument and creates a `CreateHandler` or a `VerificationHandler`. Both implement the `Handler` interface which has this method:

```
 void run(String[] args);
```

So after the switch, you can call the new handler with `handler.run(args)`, no matter which one it is.

The handlers can then examine the command lines to find out what the user wants.

Move common code (like loading/saving) into helper classes. Keep methods short (5-15 lines). Each method should do one thing. Move complex tasks into helper methods.

Comment: I agree - a common interface between the two Create/Verification classes would help significantly.

Comment: This sound like it would be very useful, but I think it might just be a hair beyond my knowledge set, and working against a deadline isn't really the best place to try new things. Thanks for the tips, though.

Comment: Upon reflection/research, I think this is more or less what I'm trying to accomplish without the benefit of knowing about handlers when I started. Essentially, (if I'm understanding handlers right) I've turned my classes into handlers. Thanks again, your suggestion was really helpful, even if I didn't end up using it, I certainly will in the future.

Comment: For more details, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern The description will scare you off but keep reading.